# Mathematical topics in computer science with applications

Tags: career

I just got my master's degree in mathematics, it was related to abstract algebra. I'm thinking about applying for a doctoral degree, however, I deeply want to study something with an "applied" appeal.

> Does anyone know a branch of computer science that can be done by math students but that can still be considered math?

Comment: I think CS mostly is math about algorithms and problems.

Comment: [Foundations of machine learning.](https://simons.berkeley.edu/programs/dl2019)

Comment: Also, numerical analysis, computer graphics, some aspects of networking. Even complexity theory and theoretical cryptography get applied nowadays.

Comment: Abstract algebra, you say? Look into functional programming, type theory, proof assistants, etc. Homotopy type theory and its programming applications is a very popular subfield at the moment.